# Detect a click on a video link in youtube

Tags: webview

I need a method where in when I click a YouTube video in my web view , I need it to perform some action , i.e just get the URL of that video link .

So , how do i get that on click on that video ?

Comment: Just need to know how can we handle a onclick on the video that we find in youtube ... rather than opening the video , i need it to go to another website

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume video extension is .mp4
In `WebViewClient`, check for the `url` with such extension. E.g.

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains(".mp4"))
        {
            downloadVideo(url);
        }
        else
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        Log.e(TAG, url);
        return true;
    }
}
```